# "Missing required primary zone" error when downloading image from iCloud

Tags: ios, swift, icloud

I'm getting a strange error when trying to fetch images form iCloud, is there anything I'm doing wrong or it's an apple bug ?

The funny thing is that works from 2-3 try, I have no idea why

```
    let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
    options.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryMode.highQualityFormat
    options.isSynchronous = false
    options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true

    options.progressHandler = {  (progress, error, stop, info) in

        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            let numFormatter = NumberFormatter()
            numFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0
            if let progressString = numFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: progress * 100)) {
                print("Downloading from iCloud \(progressString) %")
                if progress >= 0.99 {
                    self.hideLoadingLabel()
                }
            }
        }
        print("progress: \(progress)")
    }

    PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: self.selectedAsset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 300, height: 300), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: options) {
        image, info in
        self.hideLoadingLabel()
        guard let image = image else { return }

        let vc = RSKImageCropViewController(image: image, cropMode: RSKImageCropMode.circle)
        vc.delegate = self
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in iCloud. Sign out of iCloud and reboot and sign back in and it will be fixed. It has been a bug for many years.

Comment: Just would add that you can detect this string and pop up a note to the user to tell them to do the sign out, reboot and sign back in. Wish Apple would fix it. Still exists in iOS 12...

Answer (score 0):

This is a network issue. For a real life use case: I start see this error when my data plan is maxed out or has reached the next tier. In my case I login to my data providers site and agree to the next payed tier in my plan.

NOTE: It's not really a bug in iCloud since it is my service provide who is throttling the connection. Also note that in some countries data providers are required by law to get the users agreement past a specific price point.